# How can I avoid an exception when table is empty?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I want to fetch one single value from my database. Therefore I use the following code:

```
$qb->select('u.userId')
   ->from('user', 'u')
   ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC')
   ->setMaxResults(1);
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->getSingleResult();
```

The code works fine if there is at least one row in that table. But if the table is empty it throws an exception. How can I intercept this exception?

I tried stuff like `if($result->isEmpty()`, `$result === null` or `empty($result)` but my exception seems to be thrown at line no. 3 in the example above, so I can't intercept it afterwards.

Comment: Maybe you could try and catch the exception. What is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: I am already try-catching; error message is `No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.`

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
IF EXISTS(<query>)
  SELECT 'not empty'
ELSE
  SELECT 'empty'
```

Comment: I am using Doctrine because I want to avoid using pure SQL (in the example above I am using [the Doctrine QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)). So I don't consider this to be an answer I was looking for. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I'll give you +1 because it is a valid answer which would solve my problem.